# Example of a workflow pulling lookup column data for use in a calculated value column

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, lookup-column, calculated-column

I'm looking for an example of a workflow using SharePoint Designer 2010 that pulls information from a lookup list or via a lookup column and places it within a hidden field for use in a calculated value column. I need to circumvent the restriction placed by SharePoint on calculating a value based on a lookup column.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be too hard. Let's assume you have list A with a lookup to list B:

- create a workflow on list A
- create an update listitem step, say you want to update the current listitem, select the hidden field. For the value, select the Fx button and it will open up a dialog for you to go find the value.
- in this dialogue, in the first dropdown, select your list B, select the field you need the value of, and then there is another field with the Fx button where you are supposed to say how he will figure out what list itel to take thr field value from.
- in this new dialog, you have to select the ID field for the List B list item, and the lookup field for the list A list item.

That should do the trick. I'm typing this all from memory so I msy hsve gotten the order of things wrong ;).

Comment: Am I to assume that there can only be one list item that needs priced? I want to create a "better" order form that allows for 10 or 15 items + [price]*[quantity]. All is well be for the price/lookup, now it all looks right except maybe needing 15 workflow steps? Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: This is the first I hear if this price and product stuff :). It is indeed true that updating one list item equals at least one workflow step. If the process is genetic, it can just be created once and you can reuse it. Update your question with more info if you need more specific help.